# Kinect: Laggy frame display with loop function inside AllFramesReadyEventArgs

Tags: c#, kinect

I tried to save each joint position (xyz) into a text file. Here's section of the code:

```
      private void KinectAllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs) 
    {
    .
    .
    .
    //Some initialization code//
    .
    .
    .
      using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
                    {
                        if (skeletonFrame != null)
                        {
                            if ((this.skeletonData == null) || (this.skeletonData.Length != skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength))
                            {
                                this.skeletonData = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                            }

                            skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(this.skeletonData);

                            haveSkeletonData = true;

                            //===============
                            foreach (var skeleton in skeletonData)
                            {
                                if (skeletonFrame != null)
                                {
                                    if (skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                                    {

                                        // check the record check box

                                        //if (obj.RecCheckStat == true)

                                        if (RecordCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
                                        {
                                            //save skeleton to string
                                           Directory.CreateDirectory(folder_path);
                                            File.WriteAllText(file_path, currentSkeleton);

                                        }


                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            //===============
                        }
                    }


    }
.
.
.
//Draw skeleton-depth-color//
.
.
.
}
```

It seems that with the `foreach (var skeleton in skeletonData)` in the function, the frame will be laggy every 4-5 seconds(skeleton movement, not frame rate).

Any idea how to fix this issue? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue playing around with depth data. The first thing to note is that the Kinect is a strenuous device on the GPU and the frame updates are at the heart of it, so you have to be careful using any time consuming tasks as they will get run every frame rate or about 30 times a second. So put as little in the frame read function as possible.

Setup a timer or a separate thread that will write to your file and do the create directory only once, as right now it is creating it every frame.
In the frame reader save skeletonData to an object through a queue. Then you can have the timer/thread simply take a FIFO approach to write the data in the same order it came.

I would also change any foreachs to a for loops instead since it's a little [more  efficient](https://web.archive.org/web/20180126032859/https://www.dotnetperls.com/for-foreach) .